# Making div position change with button using JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to move my div's position when the button is clicked, but it isn't working. Here is my code:

```
<script>
    function changePosition1() {
        document.getElementsByTagName("div").style.top="300px";
    }
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="changePosition1()">click me</button>

<div style="position: absolute; height:100px; width:100px; background-color: green;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Better way to do it would be to add id="mydiv" to the div and use document.getElementById("mydiv") to reference it.

Answer (score 0):

Because `document.getElementsByTagName("div")` returns an Element Collection, not a single element.

EDIT: use `document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0]`

Comment: thnak you very much sir

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByTagName returns an array. try the first element of the array

```
document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].style.top="300px
```

Answer (score 0):

The getElementsByTagName method returns an array so you need to specify the first element of the array:

```
<script>
function changePosition1()
{
    document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].style.top="300px";
}
</script>
<button type="button" onclick="changePosition1()">click me</button>
<div style="position: absolute; height:100px; width:100px; background-color: green;"></div>
```